# Get Multiple Locations of the Same String in Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, arrays, nsstring

Is there any way to get the indices of the same string (that appears more than once) in a single array? I know I can find a specific string's location using:

```
[nameOfArray indexOfObject:@"apple"]
```

Of course, I could create a for loop essentially using the same code above and ignoring the previous "apples" found. I can't help to feel that there is a simpler (built-in) way to do this in objective-c. Am I right?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` with the "test" block being a block that tests for equality.